# Why is Python IDLE bad?

Tags: python, python-idle

My friends all recommend me to stop using python IDLE for programming, so do some online sources, some people also say that it is old-fashioned. But why is using IDLE for python programming so bad? It's true that some codes and characters doesn't work, but could there be any other recommendations for me?

Comment: Basically, it's meant to be a barebones IDE to help new people get started and run simple scripts, not a full featured editor that does everything you need it to. For example, it took them 15 years (!) to add line numbers to IDLE because it wasn't seen as a necessity.

Comment: It's not bad, it's just that there are better editors. You can try VS Code with the Python extension or PyCharm Community Edition.

Comment: *"some codes and characters doesn't work"* - Really? Can you give examples?

Comment: Part of the answer is that some people still judge IDLE by how it was 10 or more years ago.  One person who wrote 'IDLE is bad' in a comment admitted such.  I use IDLE to write patches for IDLE and we have fixed most of the bugs and misfeatures that really bother me.

Comment: @Pikamander2 Line numbers were added for 3.8.0.  What do you think is the worst thing missing today, in 3.10?  (IE, what would you have me work on to improve IDLE?)

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I'm not Pika but I have something: Every now and then, I think mostly when running a heavy expression, it hangs. Becomes grayed out and doesn't react anymore. Not just the shell window but also the editor window. Leaving me with no choice but to close, which closes both. Sometimes I've written a few new lines of code in the editor but not saved them yet, which I thereby lose. Would be good if I at least only lose the shell contents. (I'm using Windows, btw)

Comment: @nocomment  Since 3.8, all unicode chars, including emoji, like , `'\U0001f40d'`, are displayed in IDLE's Shell and editor windows if the OS and font supply a glyph for it.  However, codes >= '\U00010000', outside the Basic Multiligual Plane (BMP), disable proper operation of editing actions.  This is because tcl/tk Text widgets, and hence tkinter Text objects, do not currently support such.  So `print('\U0001f40d')` and  `print('')` both print  on a read-only output line (at least on Windows), but the latter messes up editing beyond the  character.  So use \U escapes in the editor.

Comment: @KellyBundy I don't remember seeing what you describe under the same circumstance, but I don't tend to run 'heavy expressions'.  What does that mean to you?  To investigate with respect to IDLE, we would need a specific example that works when directly run in Python.  If you do not have an example, but get one in the future, you could open a question here, an issue on https://bugs.python.org, or post to https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/idle-dev.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I had one yesterday but already forgot what it was. Usually something like `str(factorial(10**8))` or even something infinite maybe. Although I think this time it was something actually rather moderate or it was even after the computation, I remember being surprised it hung. I'll try to remember next time.

Comment: @KellyBundy `math.factorial(10**8)` is problematical for normal python also.  The difference is that control-C stops it, whereas in IDLE it does not, though Restart-shell (control-F6 on Windows), does.  But I did not see a 'gray-out'.  If the calculation did complete, printing the value in IDLE's Shell would freeze it, as would any line over a few thousand chars if not squeezed.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Sorry, I just meant that as a general example of a "heavy expression" (it came to mind because I was doing that at the moment), not necessarily as one that made IDLE hang like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people don't like Python IDLE because it has uncomfortable interface, there much other python compilers you can use like PyCharm, Sublime Text, Visual studio Code and etc.

Comment: What do you find most uncomfortable about the interface, on which OS?  Is it something about tk/tkinter or about how IDLE uses tkinter?  If the latter, I can think about possible changes.